# "Mit jemandem sein"

Tags: phrase

Ich bin Schweizer und eigentlich ist Deutsch meine Muttersprache (ein Dialekt allerdings). Manchmal höre ich den Ausdruck "mit jemandem sein", in einem Konzert von Die Ärzte fragen sie einmal das Publikum "Seid ihr mit uns?", im Sinne von "Seid ihr dabei?" oder "Macht ihr mit?".

Ich muss sagen, ich habe den Ausdruck bisher sehr selten gehört und irgendwie klingt er für mich auch nicht richtig. In meinem Dialekt gibt es den Ausdruck auch nicht, ich habe ihn erst einmal gehört im Sinne von "Ich bin deiner Meinung".

Gibt es den Ausdruck? Wie lautet dessen Bedeutung? Oder ist das *einmal mehr* eine direkte Übersetzung aus dem Englischen, die eigentlich gar keinen *Sinn macht*, mit anderen Worten, handelt es sich um einen Anglizismus?

Comment: Das empfinde ich auch so. Ich kann mir sowohl vorstellen, dass das ein Anglizismus ist, als auch, dass es regional benutzt wird.

Comment: Und am Rande bemerkt, als ich den Titel las, dachte ich, es geht um Beziehungen. Auch wenn man da normalerweise "gehen" benutzt (mit jemandem gehen), dachte ich an sowas wie: "Ich bin jetzt mit ihr (zusammen)."

Comment: Für mich ist das tatsächlich eine überflüssige Übersetzung des englischen "Are you with me". Überflüssig, da es bereits prägnante Formulierungen im Deutschen dafür gibt, nämlich die, die Du auch genannt hast. In eine ähnliche Kategorie fallen "Ich bin voller Liebe dafür" (höre ich häufig, gerade von weiblichen Bekannten) oder auch Mark Forsters "Ich bin fein damit" aus dem Lied "Bauch und Kopf".

Comment: Da bin ich ganz bei Dir.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ich denke nicht, dass es eine überflüssige Übersetzung des englischen "Are you with me" ist.

Der Ausdruck **Ich bin mit dir** steht schon in der Lutherübersetzung der Bibel:

> fürchte dich nicht, **ich bin mit dir**; weiche nicht, denn ich bin
>   dein Gott; ich stärke dich, ich helfe dir auch, ich erhalte dich durch
>   die rechte Hand meiner Gerechtigkeit. [Lutherbibel 1912 Jesaja 41:10](http://bibeltext.com/isaiah/41-10.htm)

Ich habe das bisher immer als eine Mischung zwischen "Ich bin bei dir" und "Ich bin mit dir (auf dem (Lebens)Weg)" gedeuten. Ich habe bei meiner kurzen Suche allerdings keine näheren Infos zur Deutung gefunden. Ich kenne “mit jemandem sein” allerdings auch nur von Gott, kirchlichen Vertretern und eben Musikgruppen. @O. R. Mapper hat noch darauf hingewiesen, dass es auch bei unpersönlichen Konzepten, z.B. "Friede" (oder ggf. noch "die Macht") verwendet wird.

Comment: +1, aber es ist durchaus möglich, dass es veraltet ist und dann über das Englische erneut in die deutsche Sprache gekommen ist. Aber auf jeden Fall zeigst Du, dass die Konstruktion dem Deutschen nicht fremd ist.

Comment: 'Ich kenne “mit jemandem sein” allerdings auch nur von Gott, kirchlichen Vertretern und eben Musikgruppen. ' ... oder von unpersönlichen Konzepten, z.B. "Friede" (oder ggf. noch "die Macht").

Comment: @O. R. Mapper, guter Hinweis.

Comment: An die Macht habe ich lustigerweise auch gedacht^^
Interessanterweise finde ich auch andere Übersetzungen, die dann an gleicher Stelle anstelle von "Ich bin mit dir" auch "Ich stehe dir bei" schreiben. Naja, ich bleibe dabei, dass es für mich zumindest ziemlich seltsam klingt. Oder ist da jemand nicht mit mir? ;)

Answer (score 1):

*Seid ihr mit uns?* ist eine direkte Übertragung des englischen *are you with me?*

Bei den Ärzten kann ich mir vorstellen, dass es eine (zumindest ursprünglich) reine Sprachspielerei ist, die man nicht ganz ernst nehmen sollte, so wie bspw. ihre unflektierte Verwendung des Bandnamens (…*bei den Die Ärzte kann*…) oder der Spruch *Es gibt nur einen Gott: Bela, Farin, Rod*.

Andere mögen die Floskel aber inzwischen auch als völlig normal wahrnehmen und verwenden. Wie die Antwort von Iris zeigt, gibt oder gab es durchaus deutsche Varietäten, in denen *mit* hier ähnlich *bei* verwendet wird.

*Seid ihr bei uns?* hätte allerdings eine etwas andere Bedeutung, da *bei* mehr auf den statischen Zustand, *mit* eher auf den dynamischen Prozess fokussiert. Dass das Publikum statisch anwesend sind, kann man von der Bühne aus sehen; der Sinn der Frage ist eher, ob die Anwesenden bereit sind, mit auf die musikalische Reise der nächsten zwei Stunden zu gehen, und ihr Zweck ist natürlich, die individuelle Euphorie und damit die Gesamtatmosphäre anzuheizen, also das emotionale Erlebnis zu verstärken – die Zuhörer abzuholen und mitzunehmen.